# Create programmatically SF organization

Tags: metadata

I'm wondering if it's possible to create programmatically a Salesforce organization (DEV or Sandbox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) to create a new sandbox. I do not think this works *directly* in Apex, but you should be able to make an API call against your org to initiate a creation or refresh.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
What about a dev edition org?

Comment: @AzertySF No, there's no API for creating "real" developer orgs. You can create a Scratch Org that's a Developer Edition using SFDX, but they expire in a maximum of 30 days. If you're trying to do some sort of continuous integration, SFDX is how you'd want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, You can use Salesforce SFDX command line client to create Scratch (Developer orgs),

And as its a command line you can program it as per your need.

You can go through the trailhead which will let you know the steps to do it.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/sfdx_get_started

If you are in hurry, you can just dig into the developer guide
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sfdx_dev.pdf

Comment: Thank you.
What if we want to create it using Apex?

Comment: create a new org via apex is not supported yet, probably in future. :)